# Can you weight Levenshtien to the front of the string?

Tags: levenshtein-distance

Levenshtein seems to be very.. agnostic..in terms of how it scores distance/similarity in terms.

For instance:

- Olive Garden vs Olden Garden = 3

whereas

- Olive Garden vs Olive Garden Restaurant = 11

In the real world (as I see it or at least for some applications) the latter should be weighted much more heavily.

Is there a modification or another 'distance' comparison tool that doesn't try to account as much for misspelling and transposition that would weight the second example higher because of the sheer # of 100% matches on the first part of the phrase?

Comment: I'm no expert in this, but maybe the `[Damerau-Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) yields better results than the classical Levenshtein distance, because it also supports transposing, or otherwise you can start at [Approximate string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) and inspect the algorithms listed there. I also can imagine that you would want to combine algorithms, and calculate a score based on the average of different distance algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult question to answer and I am by no means an expert on the subject, however, I have at least a partial answer to some of your questions. Additionally, you didn't specify a language, so all my examples will use PHP.

---

To the best of my knowledge there is no single comparison tool or function that is able to determine the relevance, rather than similarity of two strings. However, there are different comparison tools out there that would probably give you better results. The [`similar_text`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function in PHP, for example, returns the percent similarity between two strings and would be more accurate in what you're trying to do.

Additionally, you can account for misspellings when comparing the similarity of two strings by first calculating the phonetic "keys" of each string, and then calculating the Levenshtein distance between the phonetic keys. The best phonetic algorithm I know of for calculating the phonetic keys of strings is [metaphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone). In PHP, the [`metaphone`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php) is built in and can be used like this:

```
echo metaphone("carrot"); // prints KRT
```

The cool part about this is that if a user were to misspell carrot and instead type "carrrot," the same phonetic key would be generated (as "carrot" and "carrrot"), sound the same

```
echo metaphone("carrot"); // prints KRT
echo metaphone("carrrot"); // prints KRT
```

And obviously the Levenshtein distance between `KRT` and `KRT` is 0. The pitfall to this solution is that while `metaphone` helps with smoothing out spelling errors that don't change how a word sounds, words that are misspelled to the point where they no longer have any phonetic resemblance will not generate similar phonetic keys. In your example, Olive Garden and Olden Garden don't have the same phonetic keys, thus are still seen by Levenshtein as being relatively far apart.

```
echo levenshtein(metaphone("Olive Garden"), metaphone("Olden Garden")); // prints 2
```

### Conclusion

Even in conjunction with [`metaphone`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php), using the Levenshtein distance falls short, and is unable to provide the relevance between two strings. The best solution I can give would be to use [`similar_text`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) in conjunction with `metaphone` to compare your strings. Something like this:

```
similar_text(metaphone("Olive Garden Restaurant"), metaphone("Olive Garden"), $sim);
echo $sim; // prints 70%
```